# How can I check if 3 arrays contain a specific value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays and I want to check if a specific value is in any of the arrays.

For example:

```
$vipgold = array("tchan_c", "drbugs", "thesecondunicorn");
$vipsilver = array("bakterhaz", "sojmosicsaba", "andreja1987");
$vipbronze = array("the_camel", "teoriachaosu", "x_x_ultraslan_x_x" );


if (!in_array($login, $vipgold or $vipsilver or $vipbronze)){  // if not admin throw error and exit

$message = $pts->kocolor."Sorry but this feature avalaible only for VIP members. ";
$aseco->client->query('ChatSendServerMessageToLogin', $message, $login);

return;
```

So how can I check if `$login` exists in `$vipgold` or `$vipsilver` or `$vipbronze`?

Comment: i think somwthing wrong with this line only: if (!in_array($login, $vipgold or $vipsilver or $vipbronze)){  // if not admin throw error and exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two arrays together using `array_merge`, and then pass the result to `in_array`:

```
$vipgold = array("tchan_c", "drbugs", "thesecondunicorn");
$vipsilver = array("bakterhaz", "sojmosicsaba", "andreja1987");

if (in_array($login, array_merge($vipsilver, $vipgold))) {
  ...
}
```

Edit: Just seen you've edited your question to also include the `$vipbronze` array - you can pass as many arguments as you like to `array_merge`, so just add that in if you want to check all three arrays.

Comment: thought there was 3 arrays?  Oh I see there was an update .. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if(!in_array($login, $vipbronze) || !in_array($login, $vipgold) || in_array($login, $vipsilver))
{
    //YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

This have search for the value in the arayys separately, using multiple `in_array`s.